# how to display the column names on my csv file

Tags: c#, .net, linq, csv

I have the skipped the column names in order to make changes to the rows data. After using the `File.WriteAllLines` method to display the new file, the new file only display the row data without the column names.

Any suggestions would be appreciate.

```
public static IList<string> ReadFile(string fileName)
{
    var results = new List<string>();

    var target = File
        .ReadAllLines(fileName)
        .Skip(1) // Skip the line with column names
        .Select(line => line.Replace(' ', ',')); // ... splitting  pattern

    // Writing back to some other file
    File.WriteAllLines(fileName, target);

    return results;
}
```

Comment: If you need that first line then you can't Skip it

Comment: Use your debugger, put a breakpoint on the line File.WriteAllLines and check the items in target that you are going to write in the files.. I'm sure you will see what you did wrong! By the way, why are you returning an empty array with results?

Answer (score 2):

You could check for the index and replace only if it is not the first item

```
...
var target = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                 .Select((line, idx) => idx == 0 ? line : line.Replace(' ', ','));
...
```